# AJAX call on unload function returns content of the page?

Tags: php, ajax

This is driving me nuts!

I have a simple HTML page with an JS function that is called when the page is loaded. The script uses AJAX/PHP to make a request into a database. In this example, the PHP called page only returns a string. Though when I print the content of the answer, I just get the content of the page itself!!!????? (instead of the string returned by the PHP script)?

Here is the code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>

<script>
function parseContent()
{
    var node = document.getElementById('content');

    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onload = function () {
        if (this.status === 200 && this.readyState == 4) {
            console.log(xhttp.responseText);
        }
    }
    xhttp.open('POST', 'test.php', true);
    xhttp.send();
}
</script>

<html>
<body onload='parseContent();'>
<div id='container' style='margin: 0 auto; padding: 0; width: 960px;'>

<div id='content'></div>

</div><!-- container -->
</body>
</html>
```

The PHP file:

```
<?php
echo "this is a test";
?>
```

Result:

```
[Log]   <!DOCTYPE html> (connecting_to_the_server, line 12)
    <head>

    <script>
    function parseContent()
    {
        var node = document.getElementById('content');

        var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.onload = function () {
            if (this.status === 200 && this.readyState == 4) {
                console.log(xhttp.responseText);
            }
        }
        xhttp.open('POST', 'test.php', true);
        xhttp.send();
    }
    </script>

    <html>
    <body onload='parseContent();'>
    <div id='container' style='margin: 0 auto; padding: 0; width: 960px;'>


    <div id='content'></div>

    </div><!-- container -->
    </body>
    </html>
```

What am I doing wrong? (something surely stupid but really can't see right now).

## EDIT

This has something to do with the redirect rule I am using in the `.htaccess` file.

```
RewriteRule blabla/(.*)$ page.php?url=$1
```

If I keep the rule I get the behavior I mentioned. For exemple if you type:

```
www.example.com/blabla/something
```

then it should redirect to `www.example.com/page.php?url=something` but because of the way the rule is written, the user in the URL will still see the original URL (aka `www.example.com/blabla/something`).

Now though if I use:

```
RewriteRule blabla/(.*)$ page.php?url=$1 [R=301,L]
```

For example, then the page above produces the expected result (I do get 'this is a test' in the Ajax request response). Though in this case the user now sees 'www.example.com/page.php?url=something' which I would rather prefer avoid. I have no idea why it does that, but I am not good enough in this to know.

Comment: The Php page when called with ajax return first echo statement if there is no condition so either avoid unwanted echo or use it with if statements

Comment: It might be an issue with your web server: is it configured with the ability to run php scripts? Because if it isn't you're just going to get the text of the file you requested rather than the result of executing it. Or if you've done something weird to the routing then you just get the index.html page on every request.

Comment: your code is working at my end...what web server are you using?

Comment: @wpcode: I am using XAMPP (locally) so Apache in this case...

Comment: Try to create a temp folder and run only the code your provided; exclude what is not necessary and see if that is a server issue or code issue. If by any chance you have another local host; try that. see if server is running php properly. `(connecting_to_the_server, line 12)` , what is in line 12..is that something you didn't include in your code?

Comment: In the log window on Safari this is just the name of the page )) and line 12 is the line number where the unload function is being called from). I will keep searching and let you know when I find something ...

Comment: @wpcode: it has something to do with redirect but I don't know why yet. In fact this PHP web page (the one that has the onload function) is the result of a redirect in the .htaccess. So I call the page as page.php?some_post_data=toto. I don't know but if I remove the post data it works fine but with it gives the result I described. Even if I don't submit the XMLHttpRequest request, I get a response? very strange ...